# Remove wrning page of ngrok

Tags: portforwarding, ngrok

My teacher asked me for a React application and for me to share it through ngrok, it works, but that annoying warning home page always appears, how can I remove it in a purely frontend application?

I'm use windows        [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qzvpT.png)

I tried configuring the ngrok.yml file but it doesn't work, this is how it looks

version: "2"
authtoken: 2aStbMO6KVoROWPFAaIAYRtyPyU_7wD5b2XBiNMfnKnM2qAd2

tunnels:
app_http:
proto: http
addr: 5173
inspect: false

but before it was like this

version: "2"
authtoken: 2aStbMO6KVoROWPFAaIAYRtyPyU_7wD5b2XBiNMfnKnM2qAd2
tunnels:
app_http:
proto: http
addr: 5173
inspect: false

#enlazar_tls:true

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.